# How to center align a child div inside a parent div with css?

Tags: css, html

i am new to html and css and i couldn't figure out how to center align child div inside parent div.This is my code please answer and solve my problem.

**CSS**

```
.page {
position:relative;
width:1220px;
height:670px;
background-image:url('/Users/raghunath/Documents/raghu personel/page07.png');
}

.window {
float:center;
width:367px;
height:202px;
background-color:#c6c6c6;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}

* {
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="page">
<div class="window"><!--  i want to center align this div inside above div  -->
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: verically or horizontally or both?

Answer (score 2):

First of all there is nothing called `float:center;`, `float` has only 3 valid values which are `none`, `left` and `right`.

Inorder to center any element you need to define some `width` first and than use `margin: auto;` to center it horizontally.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/V3Suq/)

The other way to center an element is to use `text-align: center;` on the parent element, but this is a dirty way to do so.

---

You can also use CSS positioning techniques like nesting a `absolute` element inside a `relative` positioned element, and than we center it by using `left: 50%;` and than we deduct 1/2 of the total `width` of the element by using `margin-left: -100px;` (total element `width` say is `200px`). You can also `center` the element vertically.

The other way to have an element centered vertically as well as horizontally is to use `display: table-cell;` property along with `vertical-align: middle;`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/V3Suq/1/)

Comment: +1 nice solution. Just a doubt though. Don't you have to include the "table-cell" property element within a parent "display:table" element?

Comment: @VijetaShetty thank you and well, not a compulsion, but it won't harm if you declare an element `display: cell;` without `display: table;`, again, it depends on the layout we are trying to achieve :)

Answer (score 0):

to center horizontally

```
.page
{
position:relative;
width:1220px;
height:670px;
background-image:url('/Users/raghunath/Documents/raghu personel/page07.png');
}
.window
{
position:relative;
width:367px;
height:202px;
background-color:#c6c6c6;
margin:auto;
}
```

To center vertically and horizontally both

```
.page
{
position:relative;
width:1220px;
height:670px;
background-image:url('/Users/raghunath/Documents/raghu personel/page07.png');
}
.window
{
position:relative;
top:50%;
left:50%;
width:367px;
height:202px;
background-color:#c6c6c6;
margin-left:-183px;
margin-top:-101px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check here:

```
.page
{
  position:relative;
  width:1220px;
  height:670px;
  background-image:url('/Users/raghunath/Documents/raghu personel/page07.png');
}
.window
{
  width:367px;
  height:202px;
  background-color:#c6c6c6;
  margin:0px auto;  /* to align center horizontally*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "window" div is **CORRECTLY** centered within the "page" div.

Your problem is that the page div is not centered within `<html></html>`.

To achieve this add the following code:

```
.page
{
...
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
.window
{
    width:367px;
    height:202px;
    background-color:#c6c6c6;
    margin: auto 0px; /* For center. Apply same to page class*/
}
```

This may work.